# Creating Cordova Project Netbeans 8.0.1?

Tags: cordova, netbeans

I use Netbeans v. 8.0.1 normally for HTML5 Applications, either launching them through Chrome or a Android Emulator. I have Cordova installed correctly. When I try to create a Cordova project through Netbeans, I am prevented from selecting a project directory, with Netbeans alerting me that either "The folder Users/Programming/Documents/CordovaApps/TestApp already exists" or tells me that it cannot find the folder. When I first saw the former error, I deleted the TestApp folder, which gave me the latter. I checked the tutorial for this on the Netbeans Website, and this tutorial shows netbeans 7.0 and has no error, but does not show how to handle said error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Netbeans to work with cordova as I do it all through the CLI but I have found this link for you which may help. Seems that uninstalling the IDE and doing a clean install and a bit of configuration worked.

Check it out..

http://forums.netbeans.org/topic61056.html

Hope it helps.